# Configuring an IDE (PHP Storm) to include WordPress as an external library

Tags: php, wordpress, ide

I <del>like to have</del> need to have my IDE [(PHPStorm)](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/index.html) include the WordPress codebase as an external library by default.

Using the project files stored on a remote server option, I have to choose the WordPress root as the directory and download all the core files if I want to get the full benefit from the IDE.

Is there a way to include the WordPress code base as an external library that loads by default in all projects?  The feature is available for javascript libraries but I have gone through all the settings and can't find any way to add WordPress in less it's in the root of my project.

#### Edit:

Is this the wrong approach?  Does it make more sense to specify my local mirror as a subdirectory of an existing project that includes WordPress core?  All projects need to remain separate.

Answer (score 9):

You can try to put the wordpress codebase in phpstorm's settings "include path" :
But you need to do this for every project (this is how phpstorm works, but this enable you to have different php versions for your projects).

Go in File > Settings >  Project Settings > PHP
You must then locate your PHP version, then you will be able to add manually include paths, and use php.ini's include path.

Comment: Also, if you mostly do wordpress projects, you can go to File > Default Settings and do the same steps as above, then this will be set by default in future projects

Personally I checkout the latest tag from svn to a directory on my machine so I can easily track wordpress updates too.